# Blacklist recommended apps in Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

As the title says. I want to remove apps I have zero interest in from the so-called recommend apps list. Also block certain contacts from influencing the recommendations if possible.

Comment: Everybody wants to control these kind of things. But Google won't let you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the suggestions by tapping the triple dot and selecting *Not intersted*. However, Google yet doesnt allows you to *block certain people*. For now

- Either make a new gmail, one for social and other for useless stuff, including downloading apps. (You wont get recommendations in that, Just dont add you friends in that)
- Unfriend (Or uncircle) those contacts (seriously, hardly anyone will notice that as Google+ is very scarcely used)